# Mongodb index to speed up adding a connected document count field

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have a pretty simple mongo schema where documents have a parent-children relationship by each item having a `parentId` which is an other element's `ObjectId`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6368d6eca0ec1ced1fc9dbe2"
  },
  "name": "Something",
  "parentId": {
    "$oid": "6368d6eca0ec1ced1fc9dc05"
  },
  ... other fields ...
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have an aggregation for each document to also include the count of its children. I can do it by:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "my_documents",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "parentId",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      numberOfChildren: { $size: "$children" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: ["children"]
  }
]
```

The issue is, that it takes 6 seconds to return all documents this way. Without this field it takes ~50 ms, with appending a static field like `{numberOfChildren: 6}` it takes ~200 ms.

The document has an regular index `parentId_1` including only the `parentId asc`, which should help according to my SQL brain, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Is there an index that would help here, or is there a more performant way to do this apart from materializing the field, and if I need to materialize it (e.g. with MongoDB computed pattern) how do I keep it consistent the most reliably?

EDIT: The parentId index helps a lot, if I drop it the aggregation takes over a minute. My question on how to make it faster than 6 seconds still stands.

Comment: I think you've basically identified the solution - materializing the count at write time rather than paying the cost to do so when reading. The one question/note I'd have: is that aggregation, which performs this calculation across the entire source collection, representative of what your application will normally be doing? Or is it the case that you would be calculating that value for a small subset of documents that are the result set for a query? If the latter, then what does the performance hit for that query look like?

Comment: @user20042973 I’m testing it with a larger dataset than what I will have in prod for the next year. The measurements are 2ms vs 120ms there. You are right that materializing is a solution, but it seems pretty barebones in mongo where the business logic is responsible for keeping it consistent, which sounds pretty error prone. I could have also asked about “what utilities do mongo have to keep such calculated fields consistent”